# How to destroy / cleanup jsviews?

Tags: jquery, jsviews

I wish to use jsViews in a widget that can be added/removed from the DOM multiple times.

If the widget runs code like this during creation:

```
if(!$.link.widgetTemplate)
{
   $.templates({ widgetTemplate: "#widgetTemplateSrc" });
}

$.link.widgetTemplate("#myElement", someData);
```

Would `$("#myElement").remove();` cause a memory leak or would jsViews get properly disposed?

How do you unload jsviews if you do not wish to remove `#myElement` from the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, removing elements using jQuery methods such as .remove(), .empty(), .html() will trigger disposal in JsViews, and should not lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks Boris. I'm surprised it disposes even when using `.html()`

Comment: Yes, calling html("some markup") will replace content, and will trigger jQuery and JsViews cleanup code for the previous content.